# Bug in Symfony PHP documentation "How to Create a Custom Form Password Authenticator"

Tags: php, symfony

I found 2 problems in the documentation.
Can you tell me if that's a problem for you too?
On the page https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/custom_password_authenticator.html
line 43:

```
if (!$this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $givenPassword, $user->getSalt())) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException('The given password is invalid.');
}
```

Instead Of:

```
if (!$this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $givenPassword, $user->getSalt())) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException('The given password is invalid.');
}
```

line 48

```
if ($isPasswordValid) {
     *$isPasswordValid* is empty
}
```

Comment: no this not a bug. " bool isPasswordValid(string $encoded, string $raw, string $salt)" https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.html

Comment: Symfony has a PasswordEncoderInterface(first example) as well as a UserPasswordEncoderInterface(second example).  It is confusing and easy to mix the two up.  There is actually some discussion of eventually making the UserInterface go away.

Comment: Having said that, you are correct.  The example in the docs has serious problems.  You should consider submitting a pull request.

Comment: @CodeLife on line 48 the variable $isPasswordValid is not defined so it will be allways false

Comment: @Cerad, thank you, i will  submitting a pull request